# Prevent facebook from seeing real IP

Tags: linux, openvpn, facebook, networkmanager

I am using OpenVPN through networkmanager on Linux, and all is going well. However, I checked my active sessions on Facebook and it was able to see the IP address from my ISP. How can I prevent my OpenVPN connection from being bypassed so that Facebook cannot see my IP from my ISP? The result of the ip show command is shown below (though I've omitted the IP address of the VPN I connect to):

> default via 10.11.0.9 dev tun0  proto static  metric 1024
>   10.11.0.1 via 10.11.0.9 dev tun0  proto static  metric 1024
>   10.11.0.9 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.11.0.10
>   xx.xxx.xx.xxx via 192.168.2.1 dev wlp1s0  proto static  metric 10
>   192.168.2.0/24 dev wlp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.6

Comment: Simplest solution: use a VPN service which doesn't leak your identity....and/or configure openvpn not to leak your dns.

Comment: Any hints on how to do the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to disable [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC#Concerns) (Web Real-Time Communication) in your browser. It is known to compromise VPN security:

> In January 2015, TorrentFreak reported that browsers supporting WebRTC
>   suffer from a serious security flaw that compromises the security of
>   VPN-tunnels, by allowing the true IP address of the user to be read.
>   The IP address read requests are not visible in the browsers developer
>   console, and they are not blocked by common ad blocking/privacy
>   plugins (enabling online tracking by advertisers and other entities
>   despite precautions).

You can install the [Disable WebRTC](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/happy-bonobo-disable-webrtc/) add-on if you are using Firefox. I do not know of any similar extension for Chrome and Opera.

Note that web applications that rely on geo-location, camera and microphone inputs will not work with WebRTC disabled.

Comment: Sorry for the, uh, delayed reply. Chrome has an excellent extension that blocks WebRTC requests from returning your private IP. It's called WebRTC Leak Prevent.